# Editable Combobox with DisplayMemberPath / SelectedValuePath

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, combobox

I have a ComboBox in WPF:

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Value"
          IsEditable="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DescriptionCodes}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding DescriptionCode, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedValuePath="Key" />
```

`DescriptionCodes` is a `Dictionary<string, string>`, with codes matched up with friendly names.  The user also has the ability to enter their own code (as odd as that sounds, that's the 'norm' of our application suite, and the intention).

My binding however, creates the scenario that if the user types in a value, the `DescriptionCode` becomes `null`, as the value the user intputted doesn't exist in the `Dictionary<string, string>`.

Is there a way to get this working the way I want?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you want it to work: For me, it does a progressive search of the values when I type something in: "f" selects "Foo", and the SelectedValue is the key for "Foo". If I type in something it can't match that way then SelectedValue is null. I can always get the text the user typed by binding ComboBox.Text to another String property on the viewmodel, regardless of whether that string is found in the dictionary's values or not. Do you want to just forbid nonexistent values, or do something else with them?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I forgot I could get the `Text` straight out of it.  I really just want the `Text` value, if the `SelectedValue` is null.  I doubt there's a built-in way to do that.  I'll see if i can hash out a solution.

Comment: That seems easy enough.

Comment: thanks @EdPlunkett